# android application icon is white circle

Tags: android, icons, appicon

I have made some icon for my app and I have tested it on some old Samsung galaxy phone and it showed the icon is a nice square shape.

For some reason, on a newer phone + on the Emulator it shows a white circle as follows:

[image]

My manifest file looks as follows:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_custom"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_custom_foreground"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActivityTheme">
```

and my mimap is:

[image]

How can I solve it please?

Thank you

Comment: device specific Problem..?

Comment: which OS do you use..?

Comment: Using android. Dont think its specific device. Looks more like api thing

Comment: The same issue in Android OS (oreo)

Comment: I know. Oreo also deserves a solution =]

Answer (score 0):

Move the mipmap content out of the project

then create app icons with Asset studio (right click on project panel > new > Image Asset)

and set icons in manifest like this:

```
  <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond but I think it is what im doing right now and it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The fix to this is in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

if you find something like `android:icon="@drawable/*` as an icon replace it with the actual launcher icon generated by Android Studio.

In my case I replaced `android:icon="@drawable/card"` with this `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

TL:DR;
Replace icon from `@drawable/*` to `@mipmap/ic_launcher`